# Robolectric and FragmentTestUtil

Tags: android, android-fragments, robolectric

I recently learned about `FragmentTestUtil.startFragment()`. However, in using it, I am stuck. In particular, how do I get the views from the fragment so that I can check if they are visible, enabled, disabled, etc. as the case may be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just

```
fragment.getActivity().findViewById(...)
```

should work.

Comment: Thanks! This answer is so obvious now that you pointed it out.